# measure of the set of points that belong to infinitely many of $A_n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{A_n\}$ be the sets in $[0,1]$ of measure $1/2$, prove that the set of points that are
contained in infinitely many of the $A_n$’s has measure at least 1/2.

Let's call this set $G$, so $G=\limsup A_n=\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}\cup_{n=k}^{\infty} A_n$ and observe that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m(A_n)=\infty$, it follows that we can find an index $N$ such that $\sum_N^{\infty} m(A_n)\geq 1/2$ but I don't know what else I can do.
Thank you

Comment: Which measure are you considering? I guess lebesque measure. What are your conditions on the $A_n$? Your notation implies that there are countably many such sets. Considering measurable sets in the lebesque measure, there are however uncauntably many subsets of $[0,1]$ of measure $1/2$.

Comment: @wonko m is the lebesgue measure, ${A_n}$ is a sequence of measurable subsets in $[0,1]$ each of which has measure 1/2.

Comment: If a single point has measure zero you can add that point to any set of measure 1/2 which doesn't contain it without changing the measure. Or take it away from any set which does contain it. Are you sure you have specified the question correctly?

Comment: The wording of your question suggests that the $A_n$ are supposed to be all the sets of measure 1/2. Your workings and comment suggest otherwise.

Comment: @MarkBennet I think the problem wants us to show that $limsup A_n$ has measure of at least 1/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_k :=\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty} A_n$, so that $G := \limsup A_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty B_k$.

Since $B_k$ converges monotonically to $G$ and $\mu(B_1)$ is finite, we have that $$
\mu(G) = \lim_k \mu(B_k) \geq \frac{1}{2}\,,
$$
where the last inequality follows from the fact that $B_k$ is the union of sets of measure $\geq 1/2$.